# An extension of an algebraic question from my test

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be two real $n\times n$ matrices s.t. $AB=BA$. We now that $\det(A^2+B^2) \geq 0$. Is  the similar question true for $n$ matrices which commute with each other? If not, how do I generalize this question?

Comment: How does the proof go for two matrices? Does the proof generalize?

Comment: In fact, $A^2+B^2=(A+iB)(A-iB)$ and they have conjugate  determinant. And obviously, we can't generalize this proof for more   matrices.

Answer (score 1):

The following results are in this [paper](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/71B/jresv71Bn2-3p69_A1b.pdf):

Let $S$ be any set of commuting matrices. Then there is a fixed nonsingular matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ is upper triangular for each $A$ in $S$.

Let $A_j$, $1\le j\le p$, be commuting $n\times n$ matrices, and let $f=f(x_1,\dots,x_p)$ be an arbitrary polynomial in $x_1,\dots,x_p$. Then there is a fixed ordering of the eigenvalues of $A_j$, say, $\lambda_j(1),\dots,\lambda_j(n)$, $1\le j\le p$ (which does not depend on $f$), such that the eigenvalues of $f(A_1,\dots,A_p)$ are precisely $f(\lambda_1(i),\dots,\lambda_p(i))$, $1\le i\le n$.

I think it follows from these results that the eigenvalues of $A_1^2+\cdots+A_p^2$ are of two types: sums of squares of real eigenvalues of the $A_i$ (hence, nonnegative real numbers), together with eigenvalues that involve the nonreal eigenvalues of the $A_i$, and this second type comes in complex conjugate pairs (although I'm not seeing right away how to dot every i and cross every t). The determinant of the sum of squares is then a product of nonnegative reals and complex conjugate pairs of complex numbers, hence, nonnegative.

Comment: Thank you four your answer. But I still don't understand why complex conjugates combine in a right way as you wish. Their combination and order in the polynomial can be very weird.

Comment: Thank you four your answer. But I still don't understand why complex conjugates combine in a right way as you wish. Their combination and order in the polynomial can be very weird.

Comment: Yes, that's the part I said I couldn't see all the way through. I *think* the bit about the "fixed ordering of the eigenvalues" independent of $f$ takes care of that. In any event, since $A_1^2+\cdots+A_p^2$ is a real matrix, its nonreal eigenvalues come in conjugate pairs and so multiply to a positive real; the only thing to worry about is nonreal eigenvalues adding up to a negative real, so to tie up the loose ends we need to show that if that happens then it happens an even number of times. Anyway, I think I've given you a starting place.